# Using Orbeon Forms "List Forms Attachments" API

Tags: orbeon

We have the requirement to fetch an attachment to an Orbeon form from a simple automation script. We found the "List Forms Attachments" API (https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/api/persistence/list-form-data-attachments.html) and are trying to call it using a simple "curl" script that runs on the same host as the Orbeon Tomcat instance:

```
curl -v "http://localhost:8080/orbeon/fr/service/$app/$form/attachments?document=$docid"
```

This returns an HTTP 403 (Forbidden), and even after reading whatever doc we can find on Orbeon security, we're still scratching our heads over how to configure Orbeon. Is there a simple configuration example showing an Orbeon configuration that would allow the API to be called from a local script like ours? We are running Orbeon CE 2017.1.

If getting this API to work is an ordeal, the other option we'd consider would be a database solution. We have Orbeon running on a MySQL persistence layer, and the same script we're using also has access to this database. Is there an easy way to take a submitted form's XML and fetch the attachment for a given form field?

We see in the submitted form's XML that the attachment tag looks like this:

```
<File1 filename="Original Filename.doc" mediatype="application/msword" size="14236">
    file:/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/xforms_upload_7266596219758922423.tmp?filename=Original+Filename+doc&amp;mediatype=application%2Fmsword&amp;size=14236&amp;mac=fc2febb1227e93643a048fbb02abc16bba346531
</File1>
```

When we scan the orbeon_form_data_attach database table, we see a row with the file content we expect, but the file_name column doesn't match the file information in the form's XML above...in this example, the file_name on the database is `1af8cd16367470362e13f77e679c0ae590e1f4a5.bin`. Some of our forms have multiple attachments, and there doesn't seem to be a direct way to go from the form XML to the file_name in the database table.

Either of these solutions would be fine for us - we just need a way to get the attachments for a form from a simple script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reference, the relevant documentation is [Authorization of Pages and Services](https://doc.orbeon.com/xml-platform/controller/authorization-of-pages-and-services.html).

You can, although this is not to be done for production but only testing and development, open all services without authentication. See [this section](https://doc.orbeon.com/xml-platform/controller/authorization-of-pages-and-services.html#backward-compatibility). Otherwise, you need to setup an [authorization service](https://doc.orbeon.com/xml-platform/controller/authorization-of-pages-and-services.html#how-the-authorization-service-works).

Comment: Thanks for the reference - we were aware of that, but we hoped there might be an easier way.